# Discovering dependency API in a python class

Tags: python, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

In the following class:

```
class SomeClass(object):

  def __init__(self, somedependency):
     self._somedependency = somedependency

  def do_something(self):
     self._field = _somedependency.get_something()
```

Is it possible to "know" that `somedependency` has a function called get_something() at runtime just as you would know the public methods and properties of a constructor parameter in C# at compile time?

**EDIT**: I'd like to get the `somedependency`'s members and create a new type with those members, so what I need to perform an action such as "I'm calling methods and properties of this constructor parameter in the calling class. Give me all those methods and parameters as these are seen in the calling class". As I don't know the type of the constructor parameter I cannot determine this in a way you can do in static languages.

Comment: Why not? That's normal, isn't it?

Comment: How about getattr(self._somedependency, 'get_something')

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to verify that a known method exists, use `func = getattr(_somedependency, 'get_something'); if func: func()`.

If you want more inspection like what methods a class or instance has, check out the built in [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html).

Comment: inspect would give you the members of a class, however I don't think it can help with its dependencies.

Comment: I'm confused, why don't you call `inspect(_some_dependency)`?  If you mean inheritance, you can walk the inheritance tree (or MRO) with the `mro()` function.